# wrong <select> value when editing php form

Tags: php, select, drop-down-menu, edit

I really hope you can help me. 
I've done a form, where I can opt if a client I'm adding to the database is "Active or "Inactive", using a dropdown select box.
My code saves all the data correctly to the datbase, but when I want to edit the client, the option displays always as "Active", ignoring the value from the database.
I have 2 files:
**edita_clientes.php** - the form where I can edit the clients values
**salvar_edicao.php** - the file that saves the edition.

Here are the codes:

edita_clientes.php:

```
    <?php
@ini_set('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$id = $_GET["id_cliente"];
settype($id, "integer");

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("sistema");

$resultado = mysql_query("select * from tabela where id_cliente = $id");
$dados     = mysql_fetch_array($resultado);

mysql_close();

?>  

<form id="edita_pj" name="edita_pj" method="post" action="salvar_edicao.php">
                <input type="hidden" name="id_cliente" id="id_cliente" value="<?php echo $id;?>" />
                <div class="box-body">

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Razão Social</label>
                      <input type="text" name="razao" id="razao" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $dados["razao"];?>" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Nome Fantasia</label>
                      <input type="text" name="fantasia" id="fantasia" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $dados["fantasia"];?>" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="box-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label>CNPJ</label>
                    <input type="text" name="cnpj" id="cnpj" class="form-control" data-inputmask='"mask": "999.999.999-99"' data-mask value="<?php echo $dados["cnpj"];?>">
                    </div>
                </div>  
                <div class="box-body">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-9">
                    <label>Logradouro</label>
                      <input type="text" name="logradouro" id="logradouro" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $dados["logradouro"];?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <label>Número</label>
                      <input type="text" name="numero" id="numero" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $dados["numero"];?>">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box-body">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-9">
                    <label>Bairro</label>
                      <input type="text" name="bairro" id="bairro" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $dados["bairro"];?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <label>CEP</label>
                      <input type="text" name="cep" id="cep" class="form-control" data-inputmask='"mask": "99999-999"' data-mask value="<?php echo $dados["cep"];?>">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box-body">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-10">
                    <label>Cidade</label>
                      <input type="text" name="cidade" id="cidade" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $dados["cidade"];?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <label>UF</label>
                      <input type="text" name="uf" id="uf" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $dados["uf"];?>">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box-body">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-9">
                    <label>E-mail</label>
                      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $dados["email"];?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <label>Telefone</label>
                      <input type="text" name="telefone" id="telefone" class="form-control" data-inputmask='"mask": "(99) 9999.9999"' data-mask value="<?php echo $dados["telefone"];?>"/>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-9">
                        <label>Contato</label>
                      <input type="text" name="contato" id="contato" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $dados["contato"];?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                      <label>Estado</label>
                      <select class="form-control" name="estado" id="estado" value=""><?php echo $dados["estado"];?>
                        <option>Ativo</option>
                        <option>Inativo</option>

                      </select>
                     </div>
                     </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Observações</label>
                      <textarea class="form-control" name="obs" id="obs" rows="6" ><?php echo $dados["obs"];?>

                      </textarea>
                        </div>

                </div>  


                <div class="box-footer">
                    <button type="submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
                  </div>
                </form>
```

salvar_edicao.php:

```
<?php
@ini_set('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$razao      = $_POST["razao"];
$fantasia = $_POST["fantasia"];
$cnpj     = $_POST["cnpj"];
$logradouro     = $_POST["logradouro"];
$numero     = $_POST["numero"];
$bairro     = $_POST["bairro"];
$cep     = $_POST["cep"];
$cidade     = $_POST["cidade"]; 
$uf     = $_POST["uf"];
$email     = $_POST["email"]; 
$telefone     = $_POST["telefone"]; 
$contato     = $_POST["contato"]; 
$estado     = $_POST["estado"]; 
$obs     = $_POST["obs"]; 
$id        = $_POST["id_cliente"];
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("sistema");



mysql_query("UPDATE tabela SET razao = '$razao', fantasia = '$fantasia', cnpj = '$cnpj', logradouro = '$logradouro', numero='$numero', bairro='$bairro', cep='$cep', cidade = '$cidade', uf='$uf', email = '$email', telefone = '$telefone', contato = '$contato', estado = '$estado', obs = '$obs' WHERE tabela.id_cliente = $id");
mysql_close();
header("Location: consulta.php");
?>
```

Comment: mysql_ is deprecated, use mysqli_ or PDO instead

Comment: why are you using `$_GET["id_cliente"]`? You're not looping over the results of your SELECT, and your hidden input should be throwing you an undefined something..in HTML source.

Comment: add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`. You also have no values for `<option>`'s - and `<select>` does not have "value".

Comment: I'm new to php and I don't know how to loop over the results.

Comment: well this is wrong `value="<?php echo $id;?>"` look at your HTML source.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add 'selected' to the option that you want to be selected, based on a value from the form/db.  Here is an example using `$value` as the option value that you want selected.

```
<select class="form-control" name="estado" id="estado">
    <option <?php echo $value == 'Ativo'   ? selected : '' ?>>Ativo</option>
    <option <?php echo $value == 'Inativo' ? selected : '' ?>>Inativo</option>
</select>
```

Also, your `<select>` tag does not require a 'value' element..

Comment: thing is, the options should contain `value=""`

Comment: Wrapped @Fred? Do you mean the options should have a **value** attribute?

Comment: @IainMNorman I edited my comment before seeing yours here and realized it. I used the wrong term. Reload it.

Comment: @Mimi Here's an overview of the ternary operator. http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators

Answer (score 0):

The HTML **select** element does not have a value attribute. For the **select** to do what you want you need to add the **selected** attribute to the **option** you want selected. It's always showing as 'Active' because that's the first option and it is the default.

The resulting post-php HTML will need to look something like this stripped back example for 'Inactive' to be selected.

```
 <select>
     <option>Active</option>
     <option selected>Inactive</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: But if I add "selected", it will not read the value from the database.

Comment: I was showing you what the resulting HTML needs to look like. I was encouraging you to write your own php. Check [@chris-maggs's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31678551/60152) for some code you should be able to use that he's kindly written for you. I'd encourage you to learn and understand the ternary operator Chris has used in his example. You'll find it very handy in situations like this.

Understand Chris's snippet and you'll be able to fit your `$dados["estado"]` property in where it should go.

Answer (score 0):

Thank's for all the help!
The solution I've found was:

```
<?php
$resultado = mysql_query("select * from tabela where id_cliente = $id");
$dados     = mysql_fetch_array($resultado);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM estado");
?>
```

And the html part:

```
<select class="form-control" name="estado" id="estado">
                    <option selected="selected"><?php echo  $dados["estado"];?></option>
                    <option value="Ativo">Ativo</option>
                    <option value="Inativo">Inativo</option>
</select>
```